# How do I get Weceem Grails plugin to save its content across application restart?

Tags: grails, content-management-system, weceem

I have Weceem 1.0 plugin installed in an empty Grails 1.3.7 application.  I did the initial setup from the docs page, and I switched the devDB from "mem" to "file" storage.
I can create a space, populate some content, but then when I restart the application (grails run-app), my space and content is gone.

The devDB.script and other files show traces of Weceem data, but I lose the content in the newly started application.

What do I need to do to get it persistent?

Comment: Did you remove the settings dbCreate = "create/create-drop" in your DataSource.groovy file for development env ?

Comment: I'll try that, though I wouldn't expect it'll change, since the schema probably stays the same.

Comment: *That* was the problem.   I changed it to "update", so it worked.  I can't believe I was struggling with such a dumb problem.  Please post it as an answer, and I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the settings dbCreate = "`create/create-drop`" and replace it by "`update`" or "none" in your DataSource.groovy file for development environment.

Answer (score -1):

you can also start running a mongo database,

```
$ grails install-plugin mongodb
```

remove hibernate and add this to your domain class, to save your stuff to mongodb:

```
static mapWith="mongo"
```

Comment: you too low to achieve this with mongodb buddy so you have to downvote? lolz